# php is_dir wont work sometimes

Tags: php, jquery, html

so I'm listing items in a page for my movies dir and as long as there is no subdir it seems to be fine.

The page can be viewed here.
http://jnks.dyndns.org/dirlist.php

most relevant code can be picked up from there as far as the XHR to send the info the functions.php page. That all seems solid, I think, as it works for folders with files in them and no other folders.

here is the code for the functions.php

```
 $exts = array(
    '.mp4' => 'Apple Video',
    '.m4v' => 'Apple Video',
    '.ogg' => 'OGG Vorbis Video',
    '.ogv' => 'OGG Vorbis Video',
    '.webm' => 'MS Video',
    '.avi' => 'MS Video',
    '.mkv' => 'Matroska Video',
    '.iso' => 'Compressed DVD'
);

if(isset($_POST['dirName'])) {
$arg = $_POST['dirName'];
$dirList = scandir($arg);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($dirList as $dirs){
    if($dirs === '.' || $dirs === '..') {continue;} //remove dots
    if(is_dir($dirs)){
        echo '<li class="lv2" id="'.$arg.'\\'.$dirs.'" onclick="getDirList(this)">'.$dirs.'</li>'; //if dir create new nested list with function to drill down
    } else {
        $ext = strrchr($dirs,'.');
        if($exts[$ext]){
            echo '<li class="lv3" id="'.$dirs.'" data-folder="'.$arg.'\\'.$dirs.'" onclick="openFile(this)">'.$dirs.'</li>'; //if files then create new nested list
        }
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'POST variable is not set';
}
```

it seems that is_dir doesn't want to work. I have done searches and everyone else seems to be having issue with not using absolute paths. I know this isn't my issue as I have print the $arg var along with the echo line for the closing ul tag and it shows a full path and its definitely not permissions.

I have tried changing is_dir to !is_file and this allows it to list the folders but it also lists files that I don't want showing as it bypasses my ext filter(i guess I could add the filter to this but is_dir should work right?).

So basically I need some help to get this working. Am I crazy and don't understand is_dir or is there a better way?

also if anyone wants to look at the JavaScript I am using to hide the nested lists if one is already displayed please feel free. I feel that this is a very "hack" way of doing it but im still pretty new and don't know a lot of tricks. Its in the jQuery AJAX section of dirList.js

Btw, make sure you use an HTML5 compatible browser as I am using the video tag among some other HTML5 stuff. I am using chrome while developing this.

Thanks.

edit to ask another kind of related question.

I have simulated a fullscreen mode for the video tag using CSS and it works great except for it still shows the scrollbar on the right and it gets annoying on really dark scenes. Is there any way to get rid of this. It persists even if I'm in fullscreen mode in the browser too(f11). Browser is Chrome again and I have the z-index set to 10 and nothing else is set at all.

edit:

I got rid of the scroll bar by doing $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); as part of my fullscreen function and just turned it off when its toggled back.

Comment: is_dir will also fail on something like: C:\wamp\www\hmvc\resources\lang\es-ar (or nix equiv.) -  note hyphen in es-ar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_dir()` works on full file paths. You're passing it just a filename... even though that file is actually located inside the directory pointed to by `$arg`.

Try `is_dir($arg . "/" . $dirs)`.

Comment: I dont understand I am passing it a full path not filenames. if I do your suggestion I will end up tell it to scan d:\moviesD:\movies\whatever dir this will obviously not work. I am using the ID to supply the path and that is the full path to that folder.

Comment: nevermind I see what you mean scandir is only returning the new dir name and therefore is_dir is not working. makes perfect sense now. I knew it was something dumb I was missing. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem exactly is not using absolute path,

In your case, you can fix it by modify as following:

`$arg = $_POST['dirName'];` to `$arg = realpath($_POST['dirName']);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

And
`if(is_dir($dirs)){` to `if(is_dir($arg . '/' .$dirs)){`